# Load Winforms GUI from server

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for some techniques that allow me to create an application using winforms, the basic idea is to load the gui interface from server, whereas the other files resident in client computer.

It will be applied in LAN environment and the application GUI must be modified repeatedly

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you talking about _installers_? Even so, your question appears to be _too broad_ and if so may be considered _off-topic_ for SO. [ask]

Comment: @MickyD no, my idea is about the main form

Comment: Do you mean that the application is essentially a _shell_ and that the actual content of the app - window definitions; behaviour; features; is all loaded from the server? Like from a database?   Still too broad if so

Comment: Ok, here is the scenario, when the app starts up, it should load the main form from server path or some where

Comment: Yup, _too broad_.  [ask].   I did once upon a time see a similar question but for WPF.  I suspect it would be easier to do this sort of thing from WPF due to the nature of XAML which doesn't require code-behind (and you might be able to load at runtime) as opposed to WinForms which generally requires compilation

Comment: **1)** It's a _comment_ `not` an answer **2)** re _"WPF"_ -  _[...can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_ **3)** _"...decrease the value..."_ - see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

What you basically do is to put the "rendering stuff" work on the server rather on client side. you could archive this using streaming protocol BUT. WHY?

- First of all WinForm is the oldest and also the less efficiency way to build windows UI (WPF and UWP are made and always recommended to avoid old technologies like winform and javaswing)
- Second if you want to render on the server there are better approaches and technologies to do such as (Blazor serverside, ASP.NET Razor Page, or even the old Web Form would be a better idea) through the Browser.

Comment: Agreed, but not sure if OP is talking about _X Windows-style server-side rendering_